# permisos de usuario en vba

Tags: vba

estoy intentando obtener el valor de el checkbox guardado en un base de datos de mysql para ocultar una parte del menu ya que se le otorgar permisos al momento de guardar al  usuario
el valor es **1** si  es **verdadero** y **0** si es **falso** el menu se ocultara antes de logearse

```
    Case ch
      Dim valorChk As String
      chk = CType(obj, CheckBox)
      Param = Split(CStr(chk.Tag), "&")
      If (chk.Checked) Then
        valorChk = "1"
      Else
        valorChk = "0"
      End If
      If (UCase(Param(tagTABLA)) = UCase(nombreTabla)) Then
        Array.Resize(arrCampos, idx)
        arrCampos(idx - 1).nombreTabla = Param(tagTABLA)
        arrCampos(idx - 1).nombreCampo = Param(tagCAMPO)
        arrCampos(idx - 1).Valor = valorChk
        idx = CByte(idx + 1)
      End If

  End Select
Next
```

en su propiedad **TAG** del checkbox tengo lo siguiente   **1&tc_usuario&mInicio&0&CHK&1&0&1&mInicio**

¿Como hago para obtener el valor del dato guardado ya que son varios checkbox ?

Comment: Coloca tu código como texto y no como imagen para que sea mas sencillo ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

Primero de todo bienvenido al foro.

Por tu pregunta entiendo que quieres conseguir setear el valor de un CheckBox creado dinámicamente. Te recomiendo que al crearlo en vez de asignarle este código al tag también se lo asignes al nombre del Control, de esta forma podrás recuperarlo  y configurarlo fácilmente con `Me.Controls("1&tc_usuario&mInicio&0&CHK&1&0&1&mInicio").Value = [True/False]`

Comment: disculpa mi ignoracia pero apenas estoy empesando en esto de la programacion no entendi como asignarle el nombre al control